# Lines in File 1 not present in File 2 based on a column

Tags: linux, shell

I have 2 files

File 1 - IN.txt

```
08:43:22 IN 0xabc  
08:43:31 IN 0xdef  
08:54:45 IN 0xghi  
08:54:45 IN 0xjkl
```

File 2 - OUT.txt

```
08:43:32 OUT 0xdef 
08:54:45 OUT 0xghi 
08:54:45 OUT 0xjkl
```

Basically I am troubleshooting a network issue, IN.txt is packets coming in, OUT.txt is packets going out and column 3 is the packet code so it should match for the packet in the same transaction.

I want to know all IN packets that do not have a matching OUT packet.

Desired output:

```
08:43:22 IN 0xabc
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for.

```
for i in $(cat IN.txt| awk '{print $3}'); do grep -i $i OUT.txt | wc -l; done
```

Or more readable:

```
for i in $(cat IN.txt| awk '{print $3}'); do result=$(grep -i $i OUT.txt | wc -l);echo $i "|" $result; done
```

OUTPUT:

```
0xabc | 0

0xdef | 1

0xghi | 1

0xjkl | 1
```

NOTE: Only matches the packets, I didn't look at the time which doesn't seem important since you want to check packets

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text for proper formatting for code/data/ErrMsgs. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

IN=$(awk -F " " '{print $3}' in.txt)
OUT=$(awk -F " " '{print $3}' out.txt)

for i in $IN
do
    flag=false
    for o in $OUT
    do
        if [[ "$i" == "$o" ]]; then
            flag=true
            break
        fi
    done

    if [[ $flag == false ]]; then
        echo "Cannot find packet: $i in out"
    fi
done
```

Result:

```
dingrui@gdcni:~/onie$ ./filter.sh 
Cannot find packet: 0xabc in out
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fgrep` for this:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f3 < OUT.txt > OUT.txt2
$ fgrep -v IN.txt -f OUT.txt2
08:43:22 IN 0xabc
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? This works and it's simple enough.